# Capturing instance of reactive values?

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

In R Shiny, Is there a way of capturing a particular instance of reactive value so then that instance is totally unreactive? 
So I'd have a table made up of reactive values and when the user hits the submit button those values are copied over to an un reactive table which I can then go on to manipulate etc.

So in the following code, the user enters their values into a table from rhandsontable package (which is awesome btw), and all I am trying to do is convert it to a basic data frame namely *tabplot* which should be unreactive so I can go ahead and do any type of operations on it.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

seq1 <- seq(1:6)
mat1 <- matrix(seq1, 2)

tabplot<-data.frame(car=numeric(2),num=numeric(2),truck=numeric(2))

did_recalc <- FALSE

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput('table'),
  tableOutput('result'),
  tableOutput('kl'),
  textOutput('ca'),
  actionButton("goButton","Confirm"),

  actionButton("checkButton","Apply"),
  br(),
  actionButton("recalc", "Return to original values")

)

server <- function(input,output,session)({

  tabplot<-data.frame(car=numeric(2),num=numeric(2),truck=numeric(2))


  seq1 <- seq(1:6)
  mat1 <- matrix(seq1, 2)
  mat1<-data.frame(mat1)

  #creates reactive values for the data frame
  #obviously they have to be reactive values to function with the rhandsontable which is being continuously updated
  #as the documentation says "values taken from the reactiveValues object are reactive but the object itself is not
  values <- reactiveValues(data=mat1)

  #if recalc --- which connects to an action button in the ui is hit, values goes back to original data frame
  observe({
    input$recalc
    values$data<-mat1
  })

  #Where the magic happens
  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(values$data,selectCallback = TRUE)
  })

  #this changes the handsontable format to an r object
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$table))
      values$data <-hot_to_r(input$table)
  })

  #Here we create a reactive function that creates a data frame of the rhandsontable output but it is a reactive function
  fn<-reactive({
    co<-data.frame((values$data))                                
    return(co)
  })

  #Bit of testing, this demonstrates that the fn() is only updated after the button is pressed
  output$result<-renderTable({
    input$goButton
    isolate({
      fn()
    })
  })   

  isolate({
#  tabplot<-reactive({                              #Format co[desired row:length(colums)][desired column] 
    tabplot[1,1:3][1]<-fn()[1,1:3][1]
    tabplot[1,1:3][2]<-fn()[1,1:3][2]
    tabplot[1,1:3][3]<-fn()[1,1:3][3]

    tabplot[2,1:3][1]<-fn()[2,1:3][1]
    tabplot[2,1:3][2]<-fn()[2,1:3][2]
    tabplot[2,1:3][3]<-fn()[2,1:3][3]
  })

  output$kl<-renderTable({

    tabplot

  })  


  observe({
    input$goButton
    output$ca<-renderText({
      tabplot$car 
      cat('\nAccessing Subset with $:', tabplot$car)
      cat('\nAccessing specific cell:',tabplot[1,3])
      cat('\noperations on specific cell:',tabplot[1,3]*2)
    })
  })



})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide visuals btw. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks @InfiniteFlashChess I have attached my script and it runs without errors just doesn't do what I want!

Comment: All I want to do is copy reactive values to a normal un reactive data frame tabplot just once with a button click and then be able to use tabplot like any other data frame I am used to. Please let me know if this is possible or not, to me it seems it is quite a necessary function to have. It is not quite what the _isolation_ function provides is it?

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess when I change  `output$kl<-renderTable({

    tabplot
})` to  `output$kl<-renderTable({

    tabplot$car

  })`  I get **no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"** Being able to access tabplot like this is really what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I assume that you want to access one particular variable, so instead of `tabplot$car` (which is a vector) use `tabplot["car"]` (which remains a data.frame). Or do you really need to do `tabplot$car`?

Comment: @UnnamedUser if you're subsetting a data.frame, `drop = FALSE`, structure is not simplified if only one column is being subsetted.

Comment: @UnnamedUser Hi guys, I might not have made myself clear but the main aim here is to capture the instance of a reactive value. For example imagine you have some sort of reactive function where a user enters their numbers in and when they are happy with them they press a button and those numbers go to a non reactive data frame. So the important part is that step where you copy of those values from the reactive function to a normal data frame and hence why you should be able to use subsetting via the dollar sign but please let me know if this is wrong.

Comment: @UnnamedUser excuse the late reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you want. It leverages the much scorned `<<-` operator, but it is what I do when I need to subvert the "lazy reactive" architecture of shiny.

Note I set a parallel dataframe `tabplot1` and display it beneath where you display `tabplot`.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

seq1 <- seq(1:6)
mat1 <- matrix(seq1, 2)

tabplot<-data.frame(car=numeric(2),num=numeric(2),truck=numeric(2))

did_recalc <- FALSE

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput('table'),
  tableOutput('result'),
  tableOutput('kl'),
  tableOutput('kl1'),
  textOutput('ca'),
  actionButton("goButton","Confirm"),

  actionButton("checkButton","Apply"),
  br(),
  actionButton("recalc", "Return to original values")

)

server <- function(input,output,session)({

  tabplot<-data.frame(car=numeric(2),num=numeric(2),truck=numeric(2))
  tabplot1 <- tabplot


  seq1 <- seq(1:6)
  mat1 <- matrix(seq1, 2)
  mat1<-data.frame(mat1)

  #creates reactive values for the data frame
  #obviously they have to be reactive values to function with the rhandsontable which is being continuously updated
  #as the documentation says "values taken from the reactiveValues object are reactive but the object itself is not
  values <- reactiveValues(data=mat1)

  #if recalc --- which connects to an action button in the ui is hit, values goes back to original data frame
  observe({
    input$recalc
    values$data<-mat1
  })

  #Where the magic happens
  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(values$data,selectCallback = TRUE)
  })

  #this changes the handsontable format to an r object
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$table))
      values$data <-hot_to_r(input$table)
  })

  #Here we create a reactive function that creates a data frame of the rhandsontable output but it is a reactive function
  fn<-reactive({
    co<-data.frame((values$data))                                
    return(co)
  })

  #Bit of testing, this demonstrates that the fn() is only updated after the button is pressed
  output$result<-renderTable({
    input$goButton
    tabplot1 <<- data.frame(values$data)
    colnames(tabplot1) <<- colnames(tabplot)
    isolate({
      fn()
    })
  })   

  isolate({
    #  tabplot<-reactive({                              #Format co[desired row:length(colums)][desired column] 
    tabplot[1,1:3][1]<-fn()[1,1:3][1]
    tabplot[1,1:3][2]<-fn()[1,1:3][2]
    tabplot[1,1:3][3]<-fn()[1,1:3][3]

    tabplot[2,1:3][1]<-fn()[2,1:3][1]
    tabplot[2,1:3][2]<-fn()[2,1:3][2]
    tabplot[2,1:3][3]<-fn()[2,1:3][3]
  })

  output$kl<-renderTable({

    tabplot

  })  
  output$kl1<-renderTable({
    input$goButton
    tabplot1

  })  



  observe({
    input$goButton
    output$ca<-renderText({
      tabplot$car 
      cat('\nAccessing Subset with $:', tabplot$car)
      cat('\nAccessing specific cell:',tabplot[1,3])
      cat('\noperations on specific cell:',tabplot[1,3]*2)
    })
  })



})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: From one Mike to another, thanks for your help. Could you please give me a bit more detail of the <<- operator and what you describe as "lazy reactive architecture". So tabplot1 is still reactive but I can still access like any normal data frame now. @Mike-Wise

Comment: Also Mike, I will be wanting to do operations on the values in tabplot1. Where can I do these, does it always have to be inside a reactive output function? Hence why I'd like tabplot1 to be unreactive. Note that my understanding of reactive values in shiny could be fundamentally flawed.

Comment: From what I know now I believe it is impossible to do the following: `static_truck<-tabplot$truck` where _static_truck = 5,66_ and does not change when the values in tabplot change.

Comment: Ok so all my operations on reactive values can go inside the reactive function where the values where declared namely fn( ). It just seems a bit annoying to make the whole app reactive if that makes sense.

Comment: Hey, just saw this now. Lots of questions. To understand the <<- operator have a look at the Advanced-R book, the chapter on environments. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: I meant by a "lazy reactive" architecture, that Shiny only does things when it has to. So nothing gets calculated until it is needed in a display. The exception is if it is in an `observe` clause, and then that gets executed when the thing it is observing changes.

Comment: As to where you do your calculations on tabplot1, you will have to find a place that works, keeping in mind that stuff only gets done when something needs to be displayed, or some input value has changed.